# What is the Pythonic way to share SparkContext/Session between classes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have two classes and each of them uses Spark. Currently I init a SparkSession in the `__init__` method of one of the classes. But now I want to write a new class which will also make Spark calls. What's the Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the spark context to the `__init__` method, something like:

```py
class MySparkCallingClass:
    def __init__(self, sc):
        self.sc = sc
```

Comment: That definitely seems straightforward enough for me! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way that I don't need to explicitly provide `sc` while instantiating the class? My code is deployed on EMR cluster, so I know there is already a spark session available. Currently I just add `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` in each method in the class. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @maxymoo's answer already, but for completeness, just wanted to show how I'm going to do this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class SparkWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._spark = None

    def __del__(self):
        self._spark.stop()

    def __enter__(self):
        self._spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkApp').getOrCreate()
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        self._spark.stop()

    @property
    def spark(self):
        return self._spark

class UsesSparkClass:
    def __init__(self, sc):
        self._spark = sc

def main():
    with SparkWrapper() as sc:
        model = UsesSparkClass(sc.spark)
```